# C++ read words with 5 & 10 letters save them in new file

Tags: c++, function, file, input, output

I was trying to build a program that reads an existing text file. The words that are 5 and 10 characters long get saved in a new file. I build this program and it works fine using if statements but I am supposed to use a function `void FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(string word)`. I am not comfortable with functions yet so I would really appreciate your help on how to use a function to build this program.

This is my code without a function.

```
include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string word;
ifstream openFile;
openFile.open ("WordList.txt");
ofstream newFile ("List.txt");
if (!openFile.is_open())
{
    cout <<"Couldn't open the file" <<endl;
    return 0;

}

while (openFile >> word)
{
    int wordLength10 = 10;
    int wordLength5 = 5;
    if (word.length() == wordLength10)
    {
        newFile << word << ' ';
    }
    else if (word.length() == wordLength5)
    {
        newFile << word << ' ';

    }


}
openFile.close();
newFile.close();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You need to learn how to write a function. That's all.

Comment: How will you pass the filename with your function signature

Answer (score 0):

```
include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string word;
ifstream openFile;
openFile.open ("WordList.txt");
ofstream newFile ("List.txt");
if (!openFile.is_open())
{
    cout <<"Couldn't open the file" <<endl;
    return 0;

}

FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(openFile, newFile)

openFile.close();
newFile.close();
return 0;
}

void FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(ifstream openFile, ofstream newFile)
{
string word;
while (openFile >> word)
{
    int wordLength10 = 10;
    int wordLength5 = 5;
    if (word.length() == wordLength10)
    {
        newFile << word << ' ';
    }
    else if (word.length() == wordLength5)
    {
        newFile << word << ' ';

    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get? it is compilation error or runtime error?

Comment: if it's compilation error then try changing FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(ifstream openFile, ofstream newFile) with FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(ifstream &openFile, ofstream &newFile) . Note the & used before the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
void FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(ofstream &newFile, string word){
      if( (word.length() == 10) || (word.length() == 5) ){
           newFile << word << ' ';
      }
}
```

Then replace this chunk of code :

```
int wordLength10 = 10;
int wordLength5 = 5;
if (word.length() == wordLength10)
{
    newFile << word << ' ';
}
else if (word.length() == wordLength5)
{
    newFile << word << ' ';

}
```

with a function call:

```
FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(newFile, word);
```

Comment: I tried this function but nothing gets copied in the new file it's empty!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(ifstream &openFile, ofstream &newFile)
{
     string word;
     while (openFile >> word)
     {        
          if (word.length() == 10 || word.length() == 5) {
                newFile << word << ' ';
          }
     }
}

int main ()
{

    ifstream openFile;
    openFile.open ("WordList.txt");
    ofstream newFile ("List.txt");
    if (!openFile.is_open())
    {
         cout <<"Couldn't open the file" <<endl;
         return -1;
    }
    FindTenAndFiveLetterWords(openFile, newFile);
    openFile.close();
    newFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```